# Apache is not starting

Tags: installation, apache-http-server, xampp, configure

I have installed the xampp in windows 8, when starting the apache I am getting error

```
7:53:01 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
7:53:02 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
7:53:02 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
7:53:02 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:53:02 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:53:02 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:53:02 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:53:02 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
7:53:02 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Can someone help please.

Comment: Are you adding virtual hosts or anything? What is the output of httpd.exe -t?

Comment: use a virtual machine and install linux to learn about apache.

Comment: Before starting xampp check with `nestat -an | findstr :80` if something is listening on port 80, if yes check with `netstat -anob | more` what application it is. It could be skype as skype uses port 80 if free when starting thus apache is not able to start.
Do you have IIS running?

Comment: got it it was port issue, thanks everyone ... port 80 was busy